# Why is verification deprecated in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My Rails log is telling me `verify` is deprecated in Rails 3 and is now available as a plugin. Great, but why? There must be a good reason for this, so my main question is what is the new convention for handling something like the following in Rails 3?

```
verify :params => [:username, :password],
    :render => {:action => "new"},
    :add_flash => {
    :error => "Username and password required to log in"
}
```

The Rails 3 guide still says to use verify as we did in Rails 2. Out of date I suppose!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 3 has taken to moving a lot of "non-core" functionality into plugins to give people a chance to opt-out by default. `acts_as_tree` and `acts_as_list` are examples of things removed a while ago, now available as standard gem plugins.

If you want to use it, just add it to your `Gemfile`.